# Need an XPath expressions to locate based on a sibling

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I've got this code repeated in a div tag and want to write an XPath expression to find the dsd link so that I can click on it, based on the text in the h4 tag. Changing the HTML isn't an option.

```
<div>
    <h4>Test Block</h4>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <a href="/dsd/<generic unpredicatable text>">Option 1</a>
        <a href="otherlink/<generic unpredicatable text>">Option 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, I'm trying something like, where name is the name of the h4 tag;

```
var findSubmitButton = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/h4[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]"));
var submitButton = findSubmitButton.FindElement(By.XPath("../div/a[contains(@href,'dsd')]"));
submitButton.Click();
```

But I'm unable to get this to work. Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Any time you say that it doesn't work, please specify what result you got (as well as what result you expected). The XPath expressions you showed look about right. What was the value of findSubmitButton? of submitButton?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an issue with your xpaths. The HTML you supplied is invalid due to your placeholders, but your xpaths appear to work with this:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"
    <div>
        <h4>Test Block</h4>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <a href=""/dsd/generic unpredicatable text"">Option 1</a>
            <a href=""otherlink/generic unpredicatable text"">Option 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>";

    var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xml);

    var node = xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//div/h4[contains(text(),'Test Block')]");
    node = node.SelectSingleNode("../div/a[contains(@href,'dsd')]");

    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `//div[h4[contains(., 'Test Block')]]//a[contains(@href, 'dsd')]`. Also something like `//div[h4[contains(., 'Test Block')]]//a[contains(., 'Option 1')]` should work.

Comment: Those are unlikely to work, since in the example HTML given, the `<a>` element is not a descendant of the `<h4>` element.

Comment: @LarsH Thax. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working machine so I can't test this, but you said any feedback would be well received, so, I'm pretty sure using XPath you can grab individual elements from a child. If you know for sure that this HTML will always be the same, you could do:

```
../div[0]  //(First element of the child)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the *following-sibling*

```
var findSubmitButton = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/h4[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]"));
var submitButton = findSubmitButton.FindElement(By.XPath("following-sibling::div/a[contains(@href,'dsd')]"));
```